# Select multiples of one field

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to select individual rows within a table from a list of one column variables?

e.g. I'm trying to select just certain products from a table of products, using a list of ID numbers

Example table "items":

```
item_id    item_title    item_source
-------    ----------    -----------
123        item A        place_a
124        item B        place_b
125        item C        place_c
126        item D        place_d
```

Here's what I'm trying, but it's not working:

```
select item_title, item_source from items where item_id IN ('123','125','126')
```

I want to return:

```
item A        place_a
item C        place_c
item D        place_d
```

Comment: just get rid of the quotes `select item_title, item_source from items where item_id IN (123,125,126)`

Comment: is the type of item_id a character/varchar/text ?

Comment: I wouldn't know what else it could be, but 'not working' is a little abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just get rid of the quotes (assuming your field `item_id` is an integer)

`select item_title, item_source from items where item_id IN (123,125,126)`